# Onclick JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ther8.com there is a button on the top right as `Login` when I click on it, it shows a popup box.

I need to create a similar button and tried the below manner

```
$( "#domylogin" ).click(function() {
    $( "#fancybox-overlay" ).show( "slow" );
});
```

and the above didn't work.

Also, in Chrome inspector I tried remove div name and class name for the `Login` element and tried in the below way

`<a href="#popup2">Login</a>` and found this still works. I can't determine how this is working. I need to create another login button in same page but different area  which should display the same popup but its not displaying. Can anyone give me an idea how to fix it?

I created a `<span id="domylogin">Login</span>` and I want this to work.

I also tried as **But this too didn't work**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function anotherlogin() {
        div = document.getElementById('fancybox-overlay');
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
    document.getElementById('domyligin').onclick
    {
        anotherlogin();
    }
</script>
```

**Update1:**

I am thinking the #fancybox-overlay and its content is loading on request using AJAX but I am not much sure, can anyone open www.ther8.com and click on the login button on the top and see how the popup is being displayed.

Comment: See Adil's answer. But you also have a typo in domylogin near the bottom. (Note, Adil's answer has the same typo, but at least it's used consistently throughout.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the javascript function to onclick for binding handler.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7s2xN/)**

```
document.getElementById('domyligin').onclick = function()
{
    anotherlogin();
}
```

**Edit**

Make sure that the elements are added to DOM before you bind event to them, you can put your script just before closing tag of body.

Comment: No, didn't work. Can you please try it in console of www.ther8.com and see.

Comment: Make sure that the elements are added to DOM before you bind event to them, you can put your script just before closing tag of body.

Answer (score 0):

Do you include jQuery and fancybox library ?

From your post, it seems using those library.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment.

Comment: I am thinking fancybox library is loading on click.